# How to get the specific array from collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I have this in my collection

```
 [
  "pending" => array:2 [
           "count" => 2
           "amount" => 200
           ]
  "ongoing" => array:2 [
           "count" => 3
           "amount" => 3000
          ]
  "price_total" => 7000
]
```

what i want to achieve is like to seperate the **count** and **amount**

```
 [
  "pending" => array:1 [
           "amount" => 200
           ]
  "ongoing" => array:1 [
           "amount" => 3000
          ]
  "discount_total" => 7000
]
```

I am very new in Laravel and the concept of collection , i also tried to read the docs. but its very vauge to me .

Comment: How does the code behind this look like?

Answer (score 0):

This will only keep amount:

```
 $array = [
        "pending" => [
            "count" => 2,
            "amount" => 200
        ],
        "ongoing" => [
            "count" => 3,
            "amount" => 3000
        ],
        "price_total" => 7000
    ];
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            if (isset($item['amount'])){
                $array[$key] = $item['amount'];
            }

        }
    }

   return $array;
```